# How to enable back button in the Android

Tags: android, back-button

I have disable the back button by using the following code :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

I want to keep my back button disable till one condition in the program after the excution of that code again back button has to enable and allow user to use back.

I know how to disable the back button but I don't know how to enable again that back button again.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(CONDITION){
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just have to call `super.onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if( enableBackButton ){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This will force the normal behavior of the back button if `enableBackButton` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condition){
    finish();
}
```

That will act as back button normally do.

Answer (score 0):

check one condition for ture inside the onBackpress()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(yourcondition){
//if your condition is done
}
else{

//other logic for your condition

}
```